# TBXML not updating file

Tags: ios, xml, updates, tbxml

I use TBXML to download a .xml file from the web. I parse the file correctly and I get all the data I want as I want it.

My problem is that I updated the file on the server, and it did not update in the app. It only updated the file when I deleted and reinstalled the app.

Is there some kind of cache or something ?

This is how I order the fetch :

```
-(void)getXML {

    NSLog(@"Updating ATC data !");

    // Create a success block to be called when the async request completes
    TBXMLSuccessBlock successBlock = ^(TBXML *tbxmlDocument) {

        // If TBXML found a root node, process element and iterate all children
        if (tbxmlDocument.rootXMLElement)
            [self traverseElement:tbxmlDocument.rootXMLElement];
    };

    // Create a failure block that gets called if something goes wrong
    TBXMLFailureBlock failureBlock = ^(TBXML *tbxmlDocument, NSError * error) {
        NSLog(@"Error! %@ %@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
    };

    // Initialize TBXML with the URL of an XML doc. TBXML asynchronously loads and parses the file.
    TBXML *tbxml = [[TBXML alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/myFile.xml"] 
                                      success: successBlock 
                                      failure: failureBlock];

}
```

And this is how I call it in background:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getXML) withObject:Nil];
```

It may be useless to call it in background as TBXML works asynchronously, if someone can confirm that I'll take it away. Also, I don't think the code of my `traverseElement:` method is useful here, because the file is parsed correctly.

Thanks for any help here !

Comment: hi, please tell me how you managed to solve this problem as I'm having same issues! It keeps loading the old cached xml file and never looks at the new one from the server! I have to delete the app to make it get the new one. :(

Comment: Sorry, but as my answer says, I don't know what solved the issue..

Comment: OK Cool, does anyone else know what can actually cause this to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem vanished.. It works fine, but I have no idea why it didn't work in the first place.